# fix form size in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, webforms

I am trying to design a web form in visual basic and i have a problem.I put all the elements(buttons, labels etc) in the place i want.When i run the form i have the option to maximize the screen of the form and when i do this,a blank space appears in the form where there are no elements and all my elements are shown to the left upper side of the form. I can't see that blank space when i am designing the form. Could you help me how to fix the fix the size?
I tried autosize,autoscroll and size properties but i didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Can anyone viewing this question tell me if it's comprehensible?

Comment: I think you doesn't want controls to be in the upper left when your form is maximized, but as you are 1: specifying vb6 and vb.NET (different languages), and 2: not specifying your desired result, the question might get closed in its current format

Comment: +1 Because the question is comprehensible especially now that the VB6 tag is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify whether it's **VB6** or **VB.Net** but for once, it doesn't matter much.

Look at the form property `BorderStyle`, and change it to one of the "fixed" options.

- [VB6 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245047%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)
- [VB.Net documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)